# Angular 5 HTTP error not getting trapped, showing up in console

Tags: http, error-handling, angular5

I am consuming a web service, and when the web service returns an HTTP error, I am able to detect it, but it still showing up in the console log.  I would like to just handle it in my code, and not have it show up in the console at all.

Here is my web service code:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const url = this.getUrl('/v1/users/login');
  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'transactionId': uuid.v4()})
  };
  const body = { username, password };

  return new Observable<boolean>( observer => {
    this.http.post<User>(url, body, headers).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        console.log('login: Success: ', user);
        observer.next(true);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('login: Error: ', err);
        observer.next(false);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

and here is what I see in the console log:

`POST http://api.foo.com/card/app/api/v1/users/login 400 (Bad Request)`

I though that handling the HttpErrorResponse would stop the exception from bubbling up.   What is my code missing?